# Overlay CSS effect not working properly

Tags: html, css

i'm making a webpage and I'm having a problem. When the screen is 980px or less the menu hides itself and a 'Hamburger' like button menu appears on the screen. When you click that button a div occupies all the screen and the menu shows (that works perfectly). However, when you scroll down and click the 'Hamburger' button the overlay div just appears on it's original position. Look at this:

**THIS IS WHAT IT HAPPENS IF YOU OPEN IT AT THE TOP OF THE WEBPAGE:**

[image]

[image]

**HOWEVER, WHEN YOU SCROLL DOWN, THIS HAPPENS:**

[image]

[image]

Got it? I want the overlay effect to fit the entire screen rather than just that space at the top of the webpage, here's the page:

http://wwww.sinvender.com/hg/index.htm

If someones know how to fix this, please tell me, thanks! If you want to try it by yourself open the link above and scale your browser down..

Comment: I fixed it with a "fixed" property instead of "absolute", I'm silly, I know it :(

Comment: you might as well answer your own question or delete it ;)

Comment: anwser and leave it for other people to see it if they need to, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using "position: fixed" instead of "position: absolute" on the overlay div!